# Regex in Flutter to find double quotes enclosed words and escaped single quotes

Tags: regex, string, flutter, dart

I am using this `Regex` in my Flutter App to find words enclosed by `single-quotes` that end with a `.tr`:

`r"'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'\s*\.tr\b"`

Now I need another expression that is almost the same but looks for words enclosed by `dobule-quotes`, ending with `.tr` and *might contain escaped single-quotes*.

I tried simply changing the single quotes to double quotes from the first expression, but Flutter is giving me errors... I need to escaped some characters but I can not make it work. Any idea?

An edge case it should match is:

```
"Hello, I\'m Chris".tr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this regex for double quoted text that can have any escaped character followed by `.tr` and word boundary:

```bash
r""""[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"\s*\.tr\b"""
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WzIExD/2)

Comment: not working in Flutter

Comment: If `r"'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'\s*\.tr\b"` works for you then it is matter of entering double quoted string correctly in Flutter. Regex would be: `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"\s*\.tr\b`

Comment: Check my updated answer. Itr should be: `r""""[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"\s*\.tr\b"""`

Comment: check my updated question. it is not matching the edge case

Comment: But `"Hello, I\'m Chris"` doesn't end with `.tr`. It will surely match `"Hello, I\'m Chris".tr`

Comment: you're right, it does. Why the tripple double quotes?

Comment: Triple quotes are for Flutter string notation so that we don't need to escape double quotes anywhere in regex body so `r""""[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"\s*\.tr\b"""` should be a working regex.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `\` before every `"` in your RegExp's source, try this:

```
RegExp regExp = new RegExp(r'\"[^\"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*\"\s*\.tr\b');

print("${regExp.hasMatch('"Hello, I\'m Chris".tr')}"); // result = true
```

Comment: check my updated question. It is not matching the edge case

Comment: @Chris It mach that too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this small parser.

```dart
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/delimited.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/string_chars.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/tag.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/value.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parsing.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  const escapeChar = ValueP("'", Tag("'"));
  const chars = StringChars(isNormalChar, 92, escapeChar);
  const string = Delimited(Tag('"'), chars, Tag('".tr'));

  const input = r'''"Hello, I\'m Chris".tr''';
  final r = parseString(string.parse, input);
  print(r);
}

bool isNormalChar(int c) => c <= 91
    ? c <= 33
        ? c >= 32
        : c >= 35
    : c <= 1114111 && c >= 93;
```

Output:

```
Hello, I'm Chris
```